# How to get Terraform to start Docker Network before Docker Containers

Tags: terraform, docker-network

The First run of Terraform Apply gives "Error: Unable to start container: Error response from daemon: network vaccine-net not found"

Second run: everything works fine.

I thought Terraform manages the dependencies itself - obviously it fails here. Do I have a mistake in my file? Or can i make dependencies myself?

.tf File:

```
# Setting up docker network
resource "docker_network" "private_network" {
  name       = "vaccine-net"
  attachable = true
  ipam_config {
    subnet  = "10.0.1.0/24"
    gateway = "10.0.1.254"
  }
}

# create db container
resource "docker_container" "bootstrapper" {
  name  = "bootstrapper"
  image = "vaccine/bootstrapper"
  networks_advanced {
    name = "vaccine-net"
    ipv4_address ="10.0.1.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure your network is created before the container is created? I see no link between your network and container. Try with reference to the docker network (preferred):

```
# Setting up docker network
resource "docker_network" "private_network" {
  name       = "vaccine-net"
  attachable = true
  ipam_config {
    subnet  = "10.0.1.0/24"
    gateway = "10.0.1.254"
  }
}

# create db container
resource "docker_container" "bootstrapper" {
  name  = "bootstrapper"
  image = "vaccine/bootstrapper"
  networks_advanced {
    name = "${docker_network.private_network.name}"
    ipv4_address ="10.0.1.1"
  }
}
```

Or explicitly with `depends_on`:

```
# Setting up docker network
resource "docker_network" "private_network" {
  name       = "vaccine-net"
  attachable = true
  ipam_config {
    subnet  = "10.0.1.0/24"
    gateway = "10.0.1.254"
  }
}

# create db container
resource "docker_container" "bootstrapper" {
  name  = "bootstrapper"
  image = "vaccine/bootstrapper"
  networks_advanced {
    name = "vaccine-net"
    ipv4_address ="10.0.1.1"
  }

   depends_on = [docker_network.private_network]
}
```

Comment: I would prefer the first option! Since that is less lines of code and terraform provides such a nice way of implicitly created dependencies.